# Is there a way to wrap text in a tree viewer (Eclipse) (Not a simple Tree)

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface, treeviewer

```
viewer.getControl().addListener(SWT.MeasureItem, new Listener() {

            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                TreeItem item = (TreeItem)event.item;
                String text = getText(item, event.index);
                Point size = event.gc.textExtent(text);
                event.width = size.x;
                event.height = Math.max(event.height, size.y);
            }
        });
```

In the above code snippet the listener is added but it is not coming to handleEvent method at all.

Comment: All rows of a tree are always the same height so you can't have a different number of lines in different rows if that is what you are asking.

Comment: If so then how is it possible for a simple Tree? Please check the [link](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet227.java)

Comment: You can have multiple lines but all the rows will have the same number of lines.

Comment: That is fine for me but in the snippet I pasted above the execution never comes to handleEvent()  method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For TreeViewer do not try to add Listeners as that will interfere with the operation of the viewer.

To draw the lines yourself use a Label Provider which extends `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` and implement the `measure`, `erase` and `paint` methods.